# Prove that $ \lambda \in C $ is an eigenvalue of the linear operator $ p(T) \in \mathcal{L}(V) $

Tags: linear-algebra, eigenvalues-eigenvectors

**Question:**

Let $ V $ be a finite-dimensional vector space over $ \mathbb{C} $, $ T \in \mathcal{L}(V) $ be a linear operator on $ V $, and $ p(z) \in \mathbb{C}[z] $ be a polynomial.
Prove that $ \lambda \in C $ is an eigenvalue of the linear operator $ p(T) \in \mathcal{L}(V) $ if and only $ T $ has an eigenvalue $ \mu \in \mathbb{C} $ such that $ p(\mu) = \lambda $.

**Attempt:**

From my understanding, the setup is:
$$ p(T) = a_0 \cdot I + a_1 \cdot T + \cdots + a_n \cdot T^n \leftrightarrow p(\mu) = a_0 \cdot I + a_1 \cdot \mu \cdot I + \cdots + a_n \cdot \mu^n \cdot I = \lambda $$ I don't quite understand how to prove this statement.

Any pointers in the right direction?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you are working over the complex numbers, 
$$p(x)-\lambda=\prod (x-\mu_i)$$

Now for some vector $v$, 
$$(p(T)-\lambda)v=0$$

We have

$$\prod (x-\mu_i)v=0$$
from which is follows that one of the $\mu_i$'s is an eigenvalue. I particular $i$ minimal such that 
$$\prod\limits_{k=i+1}^n (x-\mu_k)v\neq 0$$